# ng-controller doesn't work even through it is called correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, controller, client-side

I tested the most basic angularjs. I use nodejs, angularjs and html.

Here is my files. **https://github.com/internial/test**. **node_modules is not posted b/c it was too large.**

in localhost:8080. This is the output I get.

```
{{1 + 64}}
{{main.msg}}

{{this.msg}}

{{msg}}

{{mainController.msg}}
```

Angular just doesn't work. However, it works when I don't have ng-controller and ng-app(initialized to nothing). But than I can't call the controller. I can only do the basic `{{1 + 64 }}`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have `ng-controller="mainController as main"` and `app.controller("mailController", ...`, i.e. `main` and `mail`. Fix the typo and it should be working

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: have you tried using $scope instead of this in the main controller ?

Comment: No, I have not used scope. Why use $scope?.

Comment: $scope is a holder version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to assign your controller to the proper module.

So your index.html says:

```
ng-app="firstController"
```

And your module is, in fact, called that.

```
var app = angular.module("firstController", []);
```

(Side note: I'd rename that to firstApp, maybe, since it's the name of the whole app).

Now, as mentioned in comments, rename the mailController to mainController and it should work. Look at the example:

https://jsbin.com/caqohasoce/edit?html,js,output

*Edit*: Just saw that you're using express to serve this. And your only route which is exposed only gives `index.html` - means ngapp.js never reaches the browser:

```
app.get('/', function( req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Here are two ways to resolve this. You can use express.static instead of serving files directly:

```
app.use(express.static());
```

Alternatively, you don't even need express at all here. You can either serve these files with an actual HTTP server like apache or nginx, or you can use something like `http-server` node module:

```
npm install http-server
node_modules/.bin/http-server .
```

It would serve your files instead of express.

There are further things to do here, such as moving it all into something like /public directory or similar, to separate server modules from client, but those are not relevant to your problem.

Comment: I have changed mailController to mainController but it still doesn't work. Wtf

Comment: Did you see the jsbin version? What if you straight-up copy-paste those values?

Comment: Found your problem, updating answer.

Comment: do i just use app.use(express.static()); ?

Comment: express.static() also servers static files. How is this any different from my previous code? @Zlatko

Comment: Works when I do this. app.use(express.static('./'));

Comment: why does it work when I do app.use(express.static('./'));?? It isn't even calling index.html. How does it redirect to index.html when I didn't even route it???? That makes no sense.

Comment: So the express.static() middleware is simply a function that looks up the folder you gave it and tries to find a file that matches the route from the URL requested. Eg. index.html - if there is such a file, static will find it. If you ask for ngapp.js - it will look for that. Your version did not include a route for ngapp.js - so you didn't get your angular instantiation code.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do the following..

In your ngapp.js file rewrite it to this:

```
var app = angular.module("firstController", []);
        app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
            $scope.msg = "Hello from NG controller";
        });
```

In your markup rewrite to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="firstController">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ngapp.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
{{1 + 64}}
<h3>{{msg}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Tip: Instead of `ng-app="firstController"` rename it to `ng-app="firstApp"` since it is an application.

Check the spelling `(app.controller("mailController")` and in your markup you have `ng-controller(mainController))`.